# sqllite xamarin.forms async stops responding

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do **async** with sql lite and Xamarin by following this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/store-local-data-with-sqlite/6-exercise-use-sqlite-asynchronously

[image]

```
when I do this the whole app stops responding why ?

statusMessage.Text = "";
var people = App.PersonRepo.GetAllPeopleAsync();
peopleList.ItemsSource = people;
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use await when making an async call.  `var people = await App.PersonRepo.GetAllPeopleAsync();`

Comment: thanks for the reply .... I am see definition of GetAllPeopleAsync() in attached screenshot. does that need to be done in the UI as well ? When I put it there I get a error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await

Comment: Jason I figured it out and you were correct I just didn't fully understand your answer. you want to post a answer and I will accept it Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `await` when calling an `async` method

```
var people = await App.PersonRepo.GetAllPeopleAsync()
```